# Why does this incrementing for loop return a bad variable?

Tags: bash, dash, ash, for

I'm trying to call this shell script from within the CLI of GRASS GIS:

```
for (( day=5; day<367; day+5 )); do
  # commands that I've tested without a loop.
done
exit 0
```

returns

```
Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

Comment: try `day+=5` Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps GRASS GIS pre-defines a variable named "day"?

The code doesn't work in straight bash by the way.  You don't actually increment the value of "day".

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( day=5; day<367; day=day+5 )); do
  # commands that I've tested without a loop.
        echo $day
done
exit 0
```

That works for me, bash 2.05b on a RHEL 5.0 server.

Comment: can also use `day+=5`

Comment: OT: @glenn jackman bash 2.05b? That is a release from 2003. Anyways the sniplet does work on 4.2 too.

Comment: It looks like the problem may have been using `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the script, as in the examples on the GRASS wiki, rather than `#!/bin/bash`. That, and using day+=5, does it.

Answer (score 5):

This error message comes from [ash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_shell). There are several shells with a similar syntax. Ash is a relatively basic one designed for a small memory footprint and fast execution. Another common shell is [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_shell). Bash has more features. The syntax you posted exist only in bash (and some other shells, but not ash).

In ash, you would need to write¹:

```
day=5
while [ $day -lt 367 ]; do
  …
  day=$((day + 5))
done
```

Note that depending on the Linux distribution, `/bin/sh` is either ash or bash (a few exotic ones may use other implementations). If you're writing a script that uses bash syntax, be sure to put `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

¹  <sub>Assuming you meant `day+=5` where you wrote `day+5`, otherwise it's an infinite loop.</sub>

Comment: For this case, I decided to stick with the bash solution given by Bruce, but your answer was also very helpful. Both of you caught my ash/Bash mixup.